# What's the name of the song playing in Seto No Hanayome episode 24 at around 15:13?

Tags: music, my-bride-is-a-mermaid

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHJpUN5P2yg&hd=1) is the scene where the song in question is playing.

The clip is taken at around 15:13 into episode 24, at the scene where Hideyoshi Sarutobi slapped Mikawa Kai to calm him down.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That would be [Surechigai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwbumEwFao0&list=PLHvpnzuBCCqakfbrG05pNPv95eJHhtS47&index=15), as composed by [Takanashi Yasuharu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasuharu_Takanashi)

It was included in the Seto no Hanayome Vol.3 - Bonus BGM OST 2 album as the 8th track.

Several of [set-no-hanayome](/questions/tagged/set-no-hanayome)'s albums are for sale on [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpopular&field-keywords=Seto+no+Hanayome+album&rh=n%3A229816%2Ck%3ASeto+no+Hanayome+album) So you most likely will be able to find it on there as well.